# Why doesn't my azure hosted WCF service scale when I add more machines?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, throughput

We have a WCF service which we are hosting on azure.  It takes some xml and processes it in memory (no external calls/db etc and it takes about 150ms) and returns some xml.

We have been load testing it and when we run it on 1,2 and 4 core machines we can max out the processors and get around a max of 40 calls per second throughput (on the 4 core machine).  However when we switch to an 8 core machine or two 4 core machines we still only get around 40 calls per second.

Why might I not be able to get more throughput when I scale up the number of machines doing the processing?  I would expect adding more machines would increase my throughput fairly linearly, but it doesn't.  Why not?

Comment: Could it be a problem with your load test? What happens if you run the load test from multiple machines simultaneously?

Comment: thanks Sandrino, we get the same results if we run from multiple machines...

Comment: And what does processing the XML mean? Are you calling a database, an external webservice, ... that might be the bottleneck?

Comment: no db/external call.  just some in memory crunching of the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if Azure has specific throttling, but the .NET framework has a limit on the number of outgoing connections to the same address that can be active at a time. In this MSDN article called [Improving Web Services Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx) it mentions that the default value for this is 2.

> Configure The maxconnection Attribute
>
> The maxconnection attribute in Machine.config limits the number of concurrent outbound calls.
>
> Note   This setting does not apply to local requests (requests that originate from ASP.NET applications on the same server as the Web service). The setting applies to outbound connections from the current computer, for example, to ASP.NET applications and Web services calling other remote Web services.
> The default setting for maxconnection is two per connection group. For desktop applications that call Web services, two connections may be sufficient. For ASP.NET applications that call Web services, two is generally not enough. Change the maxconnection attribute from the default of 2 to (12 times the number of CPUs) as a starting point.

```
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="12"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

> Note that 12 connections per CPU is an arbitrary number, but empirical evidence has shown that it is optimal for a variety of scenarios when you also limit ASP.NET to 12 concurrent requests (see the "Threading" section later in this chapter). However, you should validate the appropriate number of connections for your situation.

These limits are in place to prevent a single users from monopolizing all the resources on a remote server (DOS attack). Since this is a service running in Azure I would guess that they have throttling on their end to prevent a user from consuming all of their incoming connections from a single IP.

My next step would be to check and see if there is a concurrent connection limit for azure web roles ([this thread suggests there is and it's configurable)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/cbc1f1bb-9ff6-4fef-8ef2-fa3547747449) and to either increase it. Otherwise I would try to perform my load test from multiple sources and see if you still experience the same limits.

Comment: Thanks Phil, we tried some of the suggestions here, but in the end it turned out we were limited by something on our corporate network as running from outside the network doubled the performance.  I'll mark this as the answer as it linked me to a load of useful stuff.

Comment: Glad my answer was useful. I've been burned in the past by the 2 connection default in the past when our web servers would have timeout errors under heavy load connecting to other services. My Google skills are letting me down, but there was a specific guideline for the maxconnections at one point if your server is a proxy to other services (IE your website cluster must talk to PayPal or other payment provider(s)).